Correct interpretation of Impedance: IR-Drop and Nyquist plots
Good day guys,
I have been lately studying impedance and IR drop in electrochemical systems.
From my readings I have come across different interpretations.
According to my books, from the Nyquist plot:
For $\omega \rightarrow \infty $:
$$R_{uncompensated} = Re(Z)$$
(I have also seen this being referred to as 'electrolyte' resistance).
For $\omega \rightarrow \infty $ at inflection point:
$$ Re(Z) = R_{charge-transfer} + R_{uncompensated} $$
(I have also seen this 'charge transfer' resistance referred to as 'polarization resistance').
In my books they refer to the uncompensated resistance ($R_u$) as the 'potential' drop, or 'IR' drop. However, in some research papers where they had performed EIS to determine the "IR-drop" from a Nyquist plot, the reported value for the "IR-drop" was one that corresponds to,  $R_u + R_{ct}$, according to the books.
This paper in particular (DOI: 10.1021/acs.jpcc.7b10582) talks about some of the different naming conventions used, and tries to give them a more definite physical interpretation. They refer to $R_{ct}$ as the bulk-electrolyte resistance, and state that the 'IR' drop is not just $R_u$ (which they call electrode resistance), but Re(Z) at high frequencies: $R_u + R_{electrolyte} +R_{diffusion layer}$.
I often see that the overpotential is broken down into a kinetics component (activation), an ohmic drop and a concentration component. From my books, I  had understood that $R_{ct}$ was the resistance associated with the charge transfer kinetics described by the Butler Volmer equation, and the "IR drop" was given solely by the 'uncompensated' resistance component of the impedance at high frequencies ($R_u$). However, seeing other literature referring the IR drop as the real component of impedance at low frequencies ($R_u + R_{ct}$ or $R_u + R_{ct} +R_{diff}$) has confused me.
What is the best way to interpret/understand this IR-Drop?
Thank you all.

I do not have a firm answer but I like this paper and it goes into the details you are interested:  Zheng, W. iR Compensation for Electrocatalysis Studies: Considerations and Recommendations. ACS Energy Lett. 2023, 8 (4), 1952–1958. https://doi.org/10.1021/acsenergylett.3c00366.
